# creating an email recipient string list based on display names using Power automate

Tags: power-automate

I have a Power Automate case I am working on.

I have an Excel Sheet which can consist of several thousand rows. The excel sheet is stored in Sharepoint and have many columns but perhaps 3-4 are of interests: Title, Group owners, Security classification, URL.

The thing here is that I need to loop through all the rows and parse the 'Group owners' cell that consist of a string of Email Display names (Donald T; Joe B; Mike P). An inner loop must transform each display name into real email addresses and then put them together to a mail recipient string (donaldt@trump.com; Joe@whitehouse.com; Mike@thehouse.com),

And at the end of the outermost loop, the email is sent with the mail recipient string in the to field of the Email action

I have tried this with variables and that is very slow. I was thinking to use concurrency up to 50 threads, but that made a mess with the variable and I can understand that.

Is there a smart way of doing this? Perhaps parent child, concurrency, avoiding variables?

Regards Geir

[image]

Comment: I reckon it would be better achieved using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector.  You can perform joins (as long as your display names are exact) on the spreadsheet data with the `List users` data from the `MS Graph Groups and Users` connector.  Your flow would run in only seconds.  Happy to help but answering your question would almost need to be done with you one on one.  You'd need to change out the single step which gets the details based on display name so your flow would need to change a bit.

Comment: A couple of links to help get you going ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/ ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/